# List distinct names Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table in Big Query:

```
|event  |count
|event1 |1
|event2 |2
|event1 |2
|event2 |1 
|event3 |4 
|event1 |3 
|event3 |5 
|event4 |5 
|event5 |4 
|event1 |3 
|event6 |5 
|event4 |5
```

That contains 6 different events:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT event) AS Dist_event_Count = 6
```

Now I want to list the different events. What query should I do to obtain the following output?

```
|event1 
|event2     
|event3          
|event4           
|event5
|event6
```

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT event FROM YourTable` (using standard SQL)?

Comment: SELECT  
DISTINCT event  
FROM "event_dataset.event_data" LIMIT 1000                                             
 Error: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal "event_dataset.event_data" at [4:6]

Comment: Yeah, you can't put quotes around table names. I'm not sure where you saw that kind of syntax.

Comment: for legacy sql you should use [event_dataset.event_data] and for standard sql you should use \`event_dataset.event_data`

Comment: Yes I did try with ' ..'  initially but resulted errors. 
Errors:
query: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'event_dataset.event_data' at [4:6] (error code: invalidQuery)
End Time Nov 16, 2017, 4:57:52 PM                               Today when I tried with same code different error :                                                  Errors:query: Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 3, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF> (error code: invalidQuery)
End Time Nov 17, 2017, 9:33:05 AM

Comment: Working now:used backticks with standard sql.. Thanks for help  Mikhail Berlyant  and  Elliott Brossard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 'event1' event, 1 cnt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event2', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event1', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event2', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event3', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event1', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event3', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event4', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event5', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event1', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event6', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event4', 5 
)
SELECT DISTINCT event
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
```

Or  - yo can use `GROUP BY` so in this case you can also aggregate respective counts as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 'event1' event, 1 cnt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event2', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event1', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event2', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event3', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event1', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event3', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event4', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event5', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event1', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event6', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'event4', 5 
)
SELECT event, SUM(cnt) cnt
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
GROUP BY event
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Mikhail,  I have million rows and 15 columns , out million rows , I have got a distinct count  as 6(cloumn1), 43(cloumn2) on different column(1,2). I need to see the list of 6 and 43 distinct values/events.

Comment: is this a qestion? please clarify what you mean :o) and probably yo need to update your question with more specifics if above answer have not addressed your issue

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT event FROM `event_dataset.event_data`LIMIT 1000;
     With standard SQL, you would use backticks  `event_dataset.event_data`